# Using awk to substitute variables into result of a ls command

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to display which apps is deployed in each host. Using a bash script I had some success except I want to replace the following "hostname" part with the actual host name stored under the ${i} variable. I can't just substitute it because I cannot put a curly bracket inside another. EVEN if I can do it, I am still having trouble as ${i} will be replaced by the result of ls. How do I fix this?

```
hosts=(usa1 london2)
for i in ${hosts[@]}; do
    echo ---${i}---
    ssh ttoleung@${i} ls /apps | awk '{ printf("%s:%s\n", "hostname", $0) }'
done
```

Current output, based on code fragment above:

```
---usa01---
hostname:E2.gui
hostname:E1.server
---london2---
hostname:E1.gui
```

Desired output:

```
---usa01---
usa01:E2.gui
usa01:E1.server
---london2---
london2:E1.gui
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
awk '{ printf("%s:%s\n", "hostname", $0) }'
```

With:

```
awk -v h="$i" '{ printf("%s:%s\n", h, $0) }'
```

`-v h="$i"` tells awk to create an awk variable `h` and assign to it the value of the shell variable `$i`.

Aside:  we used `h="$i"` rather than `h=$i` because it is good practice to put shell variables inside double-quotes unless you want the shell to perform *word-splitting* and *pathname expansion*.

Answer (score 1):

As an intro note, it is not a safe expand array names without double quotes unless for obvious reasons because doing so would split quoted strings in array that themselves have spaces

So change

```
for i in ${hosts[@]};
```

to

```
for i in "${hosts[@]}";  # Note the quoted array
```

Now, coming to your problem, you can pass bash variables to awk using its `-v` parameter. So change

```
ssh ttoleung@${i} ls /apps | awk '{ printf("%s:%s\n", "hostname", $0) }'
```

to

```
ssh ttoleung@${i} ls /apps | awk -v hname="${i}" '{ printf("%s:%s\n", hname, $0) }'
```

Here we pass shell parameter `${i}` to `awk` variable `hname`.

<sup>**Side Note**: Don't parse `ls` output for the reasons mentioned [[ here ]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). In your case though, it doesn't make much of a difference.</sup>